# I found something confusing in the documentation at https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html# and here is what I did about it

Tags: pytest

I am learning pytest, which gives me an advantage: I'm utterly clueless, so I can I tell you what I found confusing and how I got around it.

In https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#, there are two example python files: test_module.py and test_smtpsimple.py.  What I found confusing about the examples is there are two methods, smtp_connection.ehlo() and smtp_connection.noop().  It is not intuitively obvious that these are methods of objects of class smtplib.SMTP.  Of course, they are.  I had to dig through some software to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

In https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#, there are two example python files: test_module.py and test_smtpsimple.py.  What I found confusing about the examples is there are two methods, smtp_connection.ehlo() and smtp_connection.noop().  It is not intuitively obvious that these are methods of objects of class smtplib.SMTP.  Of course, they are.  I had to dig through some software to figure that out.

So I modified the code with some comments to make it easier, I hope, for somebody learning pytest.

```
def test_noop(smtp_connection):
    # See https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtp-objects
    # The documentation there says that the noop method is not documented there.
    response, msg = smtp_connection.noop()
    assert response == 250
    assert 0  # for demo purposes
```

and

```
def smtp_connection():
    import smtplib
    # This isn't clear from https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html but smtplib has
    # at least two attributes: ehlo and noop
    print ( dir(smtplib.SMTP), file=sys.stderr )
    # Return an object of class smtplib.SMTP which has methods ehlo and noop
    return smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587, timeout=5)


def test_ehlo(smtp_connection):
    # smtp_connection is an object of type smtplib.SMTP.
    # See https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtp-objects
    # The documentation there says that the noop method is not documented there.
    response, msg = smtp_connection.ehlo()
    assert response == 250
    assert 0 # for demo purposes
```

To make it even clearer, I might print the object id of smtp_connection as it works its ways through the code.  That might be overkill.